# Check Oil Light Stays on for 20+ Seconds When 2004 Trailblazer Starts

Tags: oil, warning-light, trailblazer

Lately, my 2004 Chevy Trailblazer has been displaying the "Chk Oil" light when the vehicle first starts up for more than 20 seconds - much longer than the normal dash light test. Then is turns off and stays off until the next ignition. There is plenty of oil in the tank, and it looks clean.

I know how to reset the warning lights, but I want to make sure this isn't a symptom of a larger problem.

Comment: When did you last had the oil and filter changed?

Answer (score 2):

Second-guessing the root cause is not necessary. If you have access to an OBDII reader (roadside mechanics usually do nowadays), you can hook it up to the OBDII port and get a clear indication of what sensor is generating the warning.

I faced something similar recently and learnt that my oil pressure switch needed replacement.

Comment: There's an AutoZone down the road that does readings for free. I'll take it over there and see what they say.